# How to implement customized pagination on Birt Report Viewer

Tags: birt

I wanted to generate report using huge data load. when I'm generating a report using Birt it would load the all data and Birt report viewer will do the pagination for me. It seems like a huge performance draw back and it has been taking so long to process the report.

So I though of putting a limit queries on my scripted data source to load only the data that required to show on the current page. And My birt report viewer also should show proper pagination arrows to navigate through the report pages. and it will generate pages on demand.

I would thing anybody might have implemented this before. please help me on this.

Thanks
Amila Silva

Comment: It would be possible by creating 2 drillthrough hyperlinks "Previous page" and "Next page" in the header of the report, targetting the same report and containing a "pagination" parameter. But is your scripted datasource able to focus specific row numbers without re-scanning everything each time?

Comment: Thanks Dominique, If you have source code ref. please let me know kind fully.